# How to use Live Edit with .erb templates?

Tags: rubymine

The idea behind the Live Edit plugin by JetBrains is awesome! Coding on the fly is great for prototyping, but not only. I read that Live Edit supports the same for .erb templates (i.e. if a template was modified -> update elements on the page in browser). But I can't get it working. Does somebody know if .erb's are really supported?

Comment: for alternitives, check this: https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload

Comment: how do you run LiveEdit? In RubyMine 6 it's only supported in the javascript debug session context - see http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/LiveEdit "Rethinking LiveEdit (02 July, 2013)"

Comment: @Baldrick: sounds promising! It would also be great not only to reload, but to update/insertion/deletion of the DOM a la AJAX, if corresponding parts of views were modified.

Comment: @lena: I ran my rails apps always in debugging mode, but now I see it is something different to the javascript debugging mode, isn't it?

Comment: yes:( you need using javascript debug configuration for this